# I'm getting an error trying to connect data in R Markdown but working earlier in non markdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've had this issue before and did a quick workaround moving folder architectures but this is bugging me.

```r
vaers20 <- read.csv("Data/2020VAERSDATA.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

I'm getting an error when trying to load data saying `'No such file or Directory'`.
However, `getwd()` shows the exact directory I'm trying to link within.
`dir()` shows the correct folders in the directory, `file.exists()` shows `TRUE`.

I've connected to these data before in a regular r file, which is in same folder structure as the R Markdown file.

Console outputs below:

```r
> dir("Data")
[1] "2020VAERSDATA.csv"     "2020VAERSData.zip"     "2020VAERSSYMPTOMS.csv" "2020VAERSVAX.csv"     
[5] "2021VAERSData.csv"     "2021VAERSSYMPTOMS.csv" "2021VAERSVAX.csv"     
> dir()
[1] "Data"                        "Scripts"                     "TextMiningVAERS_Covid.Rproj"
> file.exists("Data")
[1] TRUE
> dir("Data")
[1] "2020VAERSDATA.csv"     "2020VAERSData.zip"     "2020VAERSSYMPTOMS.csv" "2020VAERSVAX.csv"     
[5] "2021VAERSData.csv"     "2021VAERSSYMPTOMS.csv" "2021VAERSVAX.csv"
```

Comment: When knitted, the .rmd files uses the directory in which the file is saved, whereas the wd of a .R script is where the .Rproj file is saved. This might be what is causing this issue?

Comment: I did not know that, thank you. This did the job!